# jQuery option in a select to Struts2

Tags: jquery, select, struts2, onchange, hidden

I'm working in a project with JSP + Struts2 + JQuery with the following functional requirement:

I have *n* Teachers that should be replaced. Once 1 teacher is selected as "Sick" the user must choose 1 colleague to replace him/her. But, if more than one teacher are sick, the user must select replacement for all of them ... and 1 replacement CANNOT be on 2 places at a time.

To achieve that, I've used some piece of jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.selbox1').change(function () {
        $('select.selbox1 option').attr('disabled', false);
        $('select.selbox1').each(function() {
            var valueSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            if (!valueSelected) return;
            if(valueSelected == "No needed") return;
            $('select.selbox1 option').filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() == valueSelected;
            }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Now, what I need to have is the selected option sent to struts2 variable. I've tried to put some hidden variable inside jQuery like this:

```
$("input[name=profeSustitutoPrimera]").val(valueSelected);
```

or this:

```
$("#profeSustitutoPrimera").val(valueSelected);
```

without any luck.

Can you please help me to get this done?

Here is the rendered HTML page that is generated after the Struts2 is sent to the client:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('select.selbox1').change(function () {
                    $('select.selbox1 option').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('select.selbox1').each(function() {
                        var valueSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                        if (!valueSelected) return;
                        if(valueSelected == "No needed") return;
                        $('select.selbox1 option').filter(function() {
                            return $(this).val() == valueSelected;
                        }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="ListadoSustituciones" name="ListadoSustituciones" action="/TFG_Sustituciones/ListadoSustituciones.action" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="fecha" value="20/01/20" id="ListadoSustituciones_fecha"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Juan" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir"/>
            Sustituciones para <b>Juan</b><br>
            <select name="selectbox1" class="selbox1">
                <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
            </select>
        <br><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Robustiano" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir"/>
            Sustituciones para <b>Robustiano</b><br>
            <select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
                <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <div style="text-align:center;"> <br><input type="submit" id="ListadoSustituciones_0" value="Confirmar Sustitutos"/></div>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

---

EDIT

---

After using @Swati code now I have duplicated values:

A,B, A,B

Exactly that way: with that extra space between 1st and 2nd iteration, right after writting the first B the loop begins again: comma=>extra space=>A=>comma=>B

A,B,_EXTRA-SPACE_A,B

I could live with that because I can take the string until I detect that blank, but it's not the best solution in case the options do have blanks (as per to separate name and surname) ... and probably I will have to face this as usual behaviour of the data coming to these selects.

The code, as of now where I have duplicated values in the backend is like this (I've removed other hidden fields for a clearer view of affected code).

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var list_of_Selected_Values = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select.selbox1').change(function() {
        $('select.selbox1 option').attr('disabled', false);
        $('select.selbox1').each(function() {
          var valueSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
          if (!valueSelected) return;
          if (valueSelected == "No needed") return;

          $('select.selbox1 option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == valueSelected;
          }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        });
        //to empty array
        list_of_Selected_Values.length = 0;
        //In the 4 lines bellow you have the attemps I've made to clear hidden field, without luck. 
        //I left one uncommented and other 3 commented, but none worked :-(
        $("#profesPrimera").text("");
        //$("#profesPrimera").val("");
        //$("input[id=profesPrimera]").text("");
        //$("input[id=profesPrimera]").val("");

        //loop through all selected values 
        $(".selbox1 option:selected").each(function() {
          if (($(this).val() != "No needed") && ($(this).text() != "--- Choose ---")) {
        //adding value in array
        list_of_Selected_Values.push($(this).val());
          }
        });
        //putting value in input box  
        $("input[name=profesPrimera]").val(list_of_Selected_Values);
      });
    });
    </script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="ListadoSustituciones" name="ListadoSustituciones" action="/TFG_Sustituciones/ListadoSustituciones.action" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" name="profesPrimera" value="" id="ListadoSustituciones_profesPrimera"/>
            Sustituciones para <b>Juan</b><br>
            <select name="selectbox1" class="selbox1">
                <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
            </select>
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="profesPrimera" value="" id="ListadoSustituciones_profesPrimera"/>
            Sustituciones para <b>Robustiano</b><br>
            <select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
                <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <div style="text-align:center;"> <br><input type="submit" id="ListadoSustituciones_0" value="Confirmar Sustitutos"/></div>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you edit your html code and provide a small piece of code for which you need to achieve above  ,so that it would be more easy to understand.

Comment: Hi @Swati ! Thanks for your quick response. I've edited my question to reduce as much as I could the HTML code I've posted earlier. What I need to do is, after the user has selected all the options in the selects, send that data into one variable for Struts2 (tipically this is either a comma separated String either a List of Strings, I can manage both)... but I need to have this data in the backend (which is a Java class that extends ActionSupport) and from the moment I've introduced jQuery the variable in the backend is always null :-( Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: So you need to put values of all select in some hidden field and pass the same, am i right?

Comment: Hi! Yes, kind of. I want to have the list of values in the backend. It could be a hidden field (cleaner for UX as I've been told) or not hidden, whatever is good for me. But I need to keep the extends of ActionSupport in the Java Backend Class to get all others struts2 values. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097735/573032

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each` and iterate through all `select-box` with same class-name i.e: `selbox1` and store its selected value in array and assign the same to some input field. 
Demo code :

```js
var list_of_Selected_Values = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.selbox1').change(function() {


    $('select.selbox1 option').attr('disabled', false);

    $('select.selbox1').each(function() {
      var valueSelected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      if (!valueSelected) return;
      if (valueSelected == "No needed") return;

      $('select.selbox1 option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == valueSelected;
      }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
    //to empty array
    list_of_Selected_Values.length = 0;
    //loop through all selected values 
    $(".selbox1 option:selected").each(function() {
      if (($(this).val() != "No needed") && ($(this).text() != "--- Choose ---")) {
        //adding value in array
        list_of_Selected_Values.push($(this).val());

      }
    });
    //putting value in input box  
    $("input[name=profeSustitutoPrimera]").val(list_of_Selected_Values);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ListadoSustituciones" name="ListadoSustituciones" action="/TFG_Sustituciones/ListadoSustituciones.action" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="fecha" value="20/01/20" id="ListadoSustituciones_fecha" />
  <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Juan" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido" />
  <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado" />
  <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir" /> Sustituciones para <b>Juan</b><br>
  <select name="selectbox1" class="selbox1">
    <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
  </select>
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="profeSustituido" value="Robustiano" id="ListadoSustituciones_profeSustituido" />
  <input type="hidden" name="diaSeleccionado" value="Lunes" id="ListadoSustituciones_diaSeleccionado" />
  <input type="hidden" name="listaProfesASustituir" value="[ProfeASustituir@6f1d1207, ProfeASustituir@2c592e59]" id="ListadoSustituciones_listaProfesASustituir" /> Sustituciones para <b>Robustiano</b><br>
  <select name="selectbox2" class="selbox1">
    <option value="">--- Choose ---</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="No needed">No needed</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="profeSustitutoPrimera" />
  <div style="text-align:center;"> <br><input type="submit" id="ListadoSustituciones_0" value="Confirmar Sustitutos" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati ! I've tried your solution and it almost works. I mean, I've just copied the code and made some minor fixes (the text to check in the last if and the name of the input)... and now what it does is duplicate the list: Finally I have A,B,A,B if I choose A in the first select and B in the second. I've tried to clear the input field with `$("input[name=profeSustitutoPrimera]").val("");` right bellow `list_of_Selected_Values.length = 0;` but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: can you edit your question and post your current code where you have made changes ? it would more easy to figure out where is the problem .

Comment: Hi @Magius you have `2 input` with same name , ofcourse the result of the jquery code will get applied to both input fields and thats the reason of getting duplicates. (Also, why do you need two input with same name , you can use one input an,d add all your selected values to it ). Nextly about your input doesn't have `id="profesPrimera"` it is `ListadoSustituciones_profesPrimera` thats a typo. Also, here you cannot assign  `same` id  to multiple inputs.

Comment: Hi @Swati ! I have 2 inputs with same name because it is a variable that came from backend POJO (and I bring it with struts2 code: `<s:set name="profesPrimera" value=""/>` and this is the ouput shown in html: `<s:hidden name="profesPrimera" value=""/>`) and it's twice because the code inside the HTML form is inside a Struts2 iterator that goes trough a list of objects to show these selects. Actually, if you pay attention to first code I've shown you can see that there are 2 inputs duplicated aswell: _diaSeleccionado_ and _listaProfesASustituir_ for this same reason.

Comment: I think this is issue of backend, if you put your input inside iterator it will give you twice as you said , i suggest you to put this input field out of iterator loop and try onces.

Comment: Hi @Swati ! I had it inside because this variable has some value before gets to the assignment to empty that I show you. I'm not in front of the code now, but I give it a try and I will let you know about the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209006/discussion-between-swati-and-magius).